# Highlight in Listboxes without permitting user selection

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

Is there a way to highlight an item in a VB.Net listbox without
allowing the user to change selection?

When I set the selection Mode to "NONE" I can´t select an item in the code.
Same when I disable the listbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the list box' Enabled property to False works fine:

```
Public Class Form1
  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(New String() {"one", "two", "three"})
    ListBox1.Enabled = False
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 1
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hmm... that was my first solution... and it didn´t work...
I´m sure... now it works... GREMLINS!

Sorry.